# 2sxc: Changing getting started dialog of apps

Tags: 2sxc

I'm trying to develop my first app, starting to create a new one...

I can't find in documentations where to change the getting start dialog https://snag.gy/JWliB7.jpg

I'm looking everywhere, configs, settings but no luck.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getting started as of now is tied in with the app catalog. The reason behind it is fairly complex, but we basically wanted to make sure that the getting-started comes from outside the app itself, so that security warnings etc. could be shown at a later time.

If you need a kind of a "user getting started" and not an admin/developer getting started, for now I recommend that you create a view like "0 getting started" so it's the first to be shown, and in those instructions you can also explain how to set this view to hidden once the user understands all.

Comment: So basically the only way to make a custom getting starter page for my app would be to modify source codes...

Comment: Any chance to get a simple way to do it in future? That is cause I would give to some users admin options and give them custom informations. Any way at the moment I will follow your "0 getting started" view suggest.
Thanks you